# AVG detecting Stack Exchange official Android app as malware

Tags: support, android-app

Just started today 2015/09/07.  Anyone else experiencing this?  Android 4.4.4, AVG 4.4.1.1.

**Edit**: As of 2015/09/09, AVG is no longer flagging the SE app on my device.

Comment: Yes, AVG reported the same for me.

Comment: Please submit a request here: http://www.avg.com/submit-sample (choosing "false alarm on Mobile App"). I highly doubt it's something on SE side.